# Linked server requires no encryption

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption

I'm trying to replicate a Linked Server from a Windows 2k3 / SQL Server 2000 to a Windows 2008 / SQL 2008 R2 setup.

The SQL 2000 Linked server is setup like this:

```
srvname=blah.blah.com
srvproduct=SQL Server
providername=SQLOLEDB
datasource=blah.blah.com
srvnetname=blah.blah.com
rpc=1
rpcout=1
dataaccess=1
```

The SQL 2008 R2 Linked Server is setup the same way.
I've copied the remote users, and all seems fine, except when i tried to connect, I get this error:

```
 OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "blah.blah.com" returned message "Client unable to establish connection". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 20)
 Encryption not supported on SQL Server
```

I still have access to the SQL 2000 machine, and can run the query fine.  I'm guessing the issue is that Windows2008 machine is trying to send data encrypted, but the linked server is saying it can't handle encryption.  Something along those lines.  I've played with various different Data Source types, and nothing seems to pan out.  I don't have access to the remote server so I don't know what OS/Database is on it.

Anyone with more SQL knowledge than me can point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried creating linked server with Provider: "SQL Server Native Client 10.0" with Provider string: "Encrypt=no;".  But that didn't help, same error message.

Comment: Also, as a test, i was able to login to blah.blah.com directly (using MSQLSMS), so it appears connection is possible, just somethings not right in my linked server properties.

Comment: Update, I think the issue might be that Windows 2008 64bit machine.  i have setup the same scenario on a windows 7 32-bit machine, and the stored procedure runs fine.  Anyone with knowledge of why 64bit would cause the error message? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray! I've done it.  For anyone that may find this issue in the future, this is what I did:

1. Create ODBC connection to SOMESERVER.COM, call it dsnSOME

   - Driver: SQL Server
   - Name: dsnSOM
   - Server: SOMESERVER.COM
2. Create a Linked Server to dsnSOM:

   - Linked server: "SOMESERVER" (I don't think it matters)
   - Provider: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
   - Product Name: dsnSOME
   - Data source: dsnSOME

And that's it.  Now when I call the stored procedure I call:

```
[SOMESERVER].database.owner.storedprocedure
```

And it works!

It seems that for whatever reason, when trying to run a stored procedure on SQL 64 bit to a SQL 32 bit linked server directly, it gives this weird message about Encryption.  However going through the ODBC and it works great.